# Flutter: update screen when coming back from another

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I've read the other answers on the topic, but I'm a bit confused.

I have this very common situation, `ScreenA` triggers the navigation to `ScreenB`, `ScreenB` does its stuff then the user taps on the back button and we return to `ScreenA`. At this point, I want to run some code but I don't understand how to do that.

This is my code for navigating to `ScreenB`:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, Router.ScreenB)
```

the navigator:

```
class Router {
  static const ScreenB = "/b";

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case ScreenB :
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ScreenB());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No route defined for ${routeSettings.name}'),
            ),
          );
        });
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, Router.ScreenB)
.then((value) {
   //do stuff
});
```

but `then()` is never called, not even if I add

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

in `ScreenB`

what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you trying to pass a value back from ScreenB to ScreenA?

Comment: @DidierPeranGanthier No they're trying to run code following a widget being popped.

Comment: So if you add a `print` statement inside `.then`, it just never prints? This shouldn't make a difference, but have you tried `await`?

Comment: Correct, I don't care about return value. Basically ScreenA contains a list, ScreenB allows you to edit list items, so when you go back from ScreenB I want to show updated items. @ChristopherMoore, it doesn't print anything. Where would you put the await? I tried before Navigator.pushNamed() to no avail

Comment: Yeah that's where to put `await`. Where did you add `Navigator.pop`?

Comment: I put Navigator.pop() on a random button on ScreenB just to try, but what I really want is to do stuff when user taps back

Comment: Would it be possible somehow to pass arguments from ScreenA to ScreenB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pop_test/router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
      home: ScreenA(),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Router {
  static const Screen_B = "/b";

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case Screen_B:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ScreenB());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No route defined for ${routeSettings.name}'),
            ),
          );
        });
    }
  }
}

class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Screen A"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Router.Screen_B).then((value) {
              print("do stuff");
            });
          },
          child: Text("Push screen B"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Screen B"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Text("Pop"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I should mention that I've renamed `Router.ScreenB` constant, due to name conflict with the screen class (maybe this is your problem?). Except this, I think, no other changes have been made. Also, usually, it is better to use `async/await` instead of `Future.then`.

By the way, you've written that you need to do something when the user taps back. If here you meant the system button, then you should use a `WillPopScope` widget. I hope this will help.

Comment: yes the ScreenA and ScreenB are fictional names I made up for the question. Changing to Navigator.of(context) worked for some reason